# Impression of tickets in thermal printer FastReport 5

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a problem on impression of tickets in continuous paper thermal printer. I have done a report with paper size "custom", height 50 cm and I have checked "Endless page height" option, but when I print the ticket, it ends when he has a height of a Din A4 page.

Any idea why? I need to configure any more?

I use FastReport 5 in Seattle 10

I have searched info about this but nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

try to mark check *Large height in design mode*, not *Endless page height* in report options, and set paper size = custom, with correct width and height (in your case 50 cm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have test it with the same result :-(

Comment: Well I tell you a configuration that worked for me. Anyway also you can check the printer driver, that reflects the custom size and continuos paper settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem without founded yet a solution until today that I'm working with C++Builder 11.1.

As a work-around, I divided the entire long report into some few different groups, each of them printed onto a new page. The grouping could be by category or some other valid concept for the user, if any.

The resulting report is going to be few pages cut at a small length than the original, but it will allow to show the whole expected information. It is not what I wanted originally but is a valid alternative solution for me.

Do you finally found a solution to reach your objective to print the report on a longer than Din A4 page?